# Twitter Bootstrap is too wide for mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I did a simple design for my site using Twitter Bootstrap. Code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie6 no-js" lang="pl-PL"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie ie7 no-js" lang="pl-PL"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie ie8 no-js" lang="pl-PL"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie ie9 no-js" lang="pl-PL"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="pl-PL"><!--<![endif]-->

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">  
    <title></title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/images/fav.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/style.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://localhost/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/js/respond.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title=" &raquo; Kanał z wpisami" href="http://localhost/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title=" &raquo; Kanał z komentarzami" href="http://localhost/comments/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=3.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
<style type="text/css">
sup {
    vertical-align: 60%;
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 100%;
}
sub {
    vertical-align: -10%;
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 100%;
}
.amp {
    font-family: Baskerville, "Goudy Old Style", "Palatino", "Book Antiqua", "Warnock Pro", serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.caps {
    font-size: 90%;
}
.dquo {
    margin-left:-.40em;
}
.quo {
    margin-left:-.2em;
}
/* because formatting .numbers should consider your current font settings, we will not style it here */
</style>
    <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
</head>

<body class="home blog">    
    <div id="wrap" class="container">
        <!-- #header -->
        <header id="header" class="span12">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h1 class="brand"><a href="http://localhost"></a></h1>
                        <div class="nav-collapse collapse hidden-mobile">
                            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                <li><a href="#about" title="O mnie">O mnie</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#showcase" title="Realizacje">Realizacje</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact" title="FAQ / Kontakt">FAQ i kontakt</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- /#header -->


<!-- #slider -->
<section id="slider" class="hidden-phone carousel slide">
    <div>
        <article class="item"></article>
        <article class="item"></article>
    </div>
</section>


    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.js?ver=3.09'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _wpcf7 = {"loaderUrl":"http:\/\/192.168.1.2\/\/wp-content\/plugins\/contact-form-7\/images\/ajax-loader.gif","sending":"Wysy\u0142anie..."};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=3.2'></script>
<script src="http://localhost/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/js/script.js"></script>

<!--

<script>

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-XX']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
-->

</body>

</html>
```

I did include Bootstrap's both css files (combined into one - bootstrap.css first and bootstrap-responsive.css next) and bootstrap.js on the bottom. But I have a very weird problem (first time since I use Twitter Bootstrap) - on my phone (Huawei Ascend) body is too wide (no matter the orientation). It seemed like it has some padding - so I removed `body`'s padding, but it didn't help. Problem is visible even if I remove my CSS and keep only Bootstrap's.

Comment: Do you get the same problem looking at Bootstrap's demo pages like this one on your mobile? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

Comment: No - and that's the problem. I checked on two other phones (both Samsungs, Galaxy 551 and Galaxy II) and it's the same.

Comment: try removing class="span12" on your header tag... you're not in a row there, so maybe that's breaking it?

Comment: That's not it either @ThomPorter. I've set `.container {width:100%!important}` and it helped.

Answer (score 3):

The Bootstrap version was not specified in the question, although it was posted before the release of v3.0.

In any case, if anyone happens to come across this topic and has this same problem with v3.x, here's what I did. YMMV depending on whether or not your .container divs come directly below <body> or not..

```
/* Fix for viewport being too wide below smallest breakpoint */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body > .container { overflow: hidden; } /* fix */
    body > .container > * { overflow: visible; } /* reset back to normal */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a very bad fix.  Try changing `.container` to `.container-fluid` and see what happens...

setting the width to 100% will give you other headaches down the line...

Comment: It's the only one working so far. If you have any ideas how to avoid setting `container` to `100%` I'd love to hear it (really, no sarcarm :)).

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `.container` to `.container-fluid` and adding `<div class="row-fluid">` as the direct child of `.container-fluid`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
.container { width: 100% !important }
```

helped. I still don't know why this even happened.